# Question on XSLT to eliminate parent node where child is in CDATA section

Tags: xslt

I have an original XML message which looks like below.

```
<Message>
    <Header>
        <MsgVerNo>1.0</MsgVerNo>
        <SourceId>XXX</SourceId>
        <MsgRefNo>1234567890</MsgRefNo>
        <LoginId>007</LoginId>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <![CDATA[<txn>
<id>1234567</id>
<name>XXXX</name>
        </txn>]]>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

I wish to transform it as below.  and  should be removed while child nodes should be remained. In addition, CData which wrap  should be removed as well.

```
<Message>
    <MsgVerNo>1.0</MsgVerNo>
    <SourceId>XXX</SourceId>
    <MsgRefNo>1234567890</MsgRefNo>
    <LoginId>007</LoginId>
    <txn>
        <record>
            <id>1234567</id>
            <name>XXXX</name>
        </record>
    </txn>
</Message>
```

I tried to use below XSLT. But the output is not desired.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Message>
<MsgVerNo>1.0</MsgVerNo>
<SourceId>XXX</SourceId>
<MsgRefNo>1234567890</MsgRefNo>
<LoginId>007</LoginId>
    &lt;txn&gt;
&lt;id&gt;1234567&lt;/id&gt;
&lt;name&gt;XXXX&lt;/name&gt;
    &lt;/txn&gt;
</Message>
```

I have no luck so far. Any help from expert please. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 3.0? If so, the `parse-xml` method would be available to handle this, which would have the advantage that you could then make transformations to that XML if you wanted.

Comment: @TimC I can't use XSLT 3.0

Comment: The key thing here is that the `txn` element is not a child of the Body element. In fact there is no `txn` element. The CDATA tags tell the parser "even if the stuff in here looks like XML, don't treat it as XML, treat it as plain text. But you want it treated as XML.

Answer (score 2):

The CDATA element means that the data in between will not be interpreted as XML by your parse.  This is specifically the purpose of CDATA. You can send character data, including < > without the parser trying to interpret it and potentially failing.

For all intents and purposes your Body node just contains text. You can read it as text and even strip the CDATA tag, however that still leaves you with text that looks like XML instead of something that is interpreted as XML.

You could use the following to get the contents, however if you wanted to further parse the contents of the body element you would have to pass it on to another XSLT for example.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the <record> tag after <txn>. I'm not too sure with your sentence on "pass it on to another XSLT". Could you please elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: You can probably ignore that comment, this only matters if you would want to further transform the xml that was originally in the CDATA tag. This goes a bit beyond your original question.  However the current XSLT outputs XML, and you would need another to actually be able to transform the XML that was in the CDATA block originally.